# Implementing progress bar with custom color in angular 2 and bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap progress bar using the ng-bootstrap components. The documentation provides 4 types of coloring using the directive "type" which can only be one of 4: "success", "info", "warning" or "danger". (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar)

I made sure that all colors are customized in my variables sass folder to override the default variables of bootstrap.

Yet the bar is appearing in the color blue when using primary.

Progress bar code:

```
<ngb-progressbar type="primary" [value]="25"></ngb-progressbar>
```

CSS trials:

```
//Doesn't work - no effect what so ever - this style is placed in a global stylesheet in order to have access to the progress bar.
.progress.progress-primary{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to change that color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 does not change the progress bar based on predefined variables. The $progress-bar-color variable is hard coded and was causing the trouble.

Fixed now.